# Python script to convert hierarchical JSON to LaTeX itemize

Tags: python, json, stack, depth-first-search

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "item": "abc",
      "status": "ready"
    },
    {
      "item": "def",
      "status": "ready"
    },
    {
      "item": "ghi",
      "status": "done",
      "items": [
        {
          "item": "ABC",
          "status": "ready"
        },
        {
          "item": "DEF",
          "status": "ready"
        },
        {
          "item": "GHI",
          "status": "done"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

which I would like to convert to:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item abc\hfill{}ready
    \item def\hfill{}ready
    \item ghi\hfill{}done
      \begin{itemize}
      \item ABC\hfill{}ready
      \item DEF\hfill{}ready
      \item GHI\hfill{}done
      \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

The `items` can be nested arbitrarily deep. I have the following Python code:

```
import json
import os

TAB = '  '
BEGIN = '\\begin{itemize}'
ITEM = '\\item {0}\\hfill{{}}{1}'
END = '\\end{itemize}'

def main(path):
    with open(os.path.join(path, 'test.json')) as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)
    print('\n'.join(convert(data)))

def convert(data):
    stack = [data['items'].__iter__()]
    yield (TAB * (len(stack) - 1)) + BEGIN
    while len(stack) > 0:
        iterator = stack[len(stack) - 1]
        try:
            current = iterator.next()
            yield (TAB * (len(stack) - 1)) + ITEM.format(current['item'], current['status'])
            try:
                stack.append(current['items'].__iter__())
                yield (TAB * (len(stack) - 1)) + BEGIN
            except KeyError:
                pass
        except StopIteration:
            yield (TAB * (len(stack) - 1)) + END
            stack.pop()
```

I am new to Python and am looking for suggestions for the code to be more idiomatic Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you specifically want a tab of 2 spaces in the resulting LaTeX, you can use `'\t'` to get the actual tab character.

```
TAB = '\t'
```

When working with strings with one or more backslashes, you can declare them as 'raw' strings by prefixing them with an `r`, which allows you to write backslash characters without having to escape them.

```
BEGIN = r'\begin{itemize}'
ITEM = r'\item {0}\hfill{{}}{1}'
END = r'\end{itemize}'
```

You can use the [magic method iter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) to get iterators, for example:

```
stack = [iter(data['items'])]
```

or

```
stack.append(iter(current['items']))
```

This is more idiomatic than calling the `__iter__()` method directly. In addition, there is a `next()` magic method as well which you can use to get the next item from an iterator.

```
current = next(iterator)
```

If you are using Python 3.4 or higher, I'd recommend checking out the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module for manipulating file paths over `os.path`, but in this case using `os.path` does the job and is probably sufficient.